# Codeigniter File Upload Not Working On Live Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, localhost

I cant upload the image into the folder online, but it works perfectly on localhost.

Below Is My Code

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
if (empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {
    $image=$this->input->post('image');
} else {
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => "uploads/",
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
    );
    $this->load->library('upload',$config); 

    if($this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $image = $upload_data['file_name'];
    } else {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        redirect(base_url().'uploaderror');
    }
}
```

Please help finding the solution
Thanks

Guys Thanks for your help the problem was with the php version in the server
i fixed it

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: its not showing any error

Comment: check your server folder permission. it should be 777. image name is updating into database?

Comment: i have set it to 777 and name is also not updating

Comment: Check your error log and if there is any errors please Edit/Update the question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple problem of file limit and it may be solved by these setups in your php.ini file which you get in xampp->php->php.ini or in your wamp->php->php.ini (not clear about wamp path but you somewhere PHP folder) -

```
post_max_size=1024M
upload_max_size=1500M
memory_limit=128M //For unlimited set -1
max_execution_time=3600
```

There is another easy option without touching the php.ini file is just you define them in your controller or where ever

```
ini_set('post_max_size','99500M');
ini_set('upload_max_size','100000M');
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
ini_set('max_execution_time','5000');
```

It's sample max setup but you change as per your requirment.

Answer (score 2):

it may be due to php server version and it's option.

1).logging to your cpanel account

2).in the software section,click "Select PHP Version".

3).tap the "fileinfo" chexbox in the php option like following photo.

[![tap the "fileinfo chexbox"][and save]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDwn7.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
$base_path = $this->config->item('upload_path');

        $config['upload_path'] = $base_path.'/folder_name/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = config('allowed_extensions');
        $config['max_size'] = config('max_upload_file_size');
        $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
        $file_name = '';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

check this code.

Comment: Still Same Problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your controller

```
<?php
        public function _upload_files()
        {
                $this->session->unset_userdata('upload_data');
                $config['upload_path']          = FCPATH.'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                $this->_check_file_upload_path($config['upload_path']);// check if upload path exists, if not creates one
                $config['allowed_types']        = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg";
                $config['encrypt_name']         = TRUE;// file name will be encrypted
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('photo'))
                {
                        echo $this->upload->display_errors('','');
                        return FALSE;
                }       
                var_dump($this->upload->data());

        }

        private function _check_file_upload_path($upload_path)
        {
                if(! is_dir($upload_path))
                        mkdir($upload_path,0777,TRUE);
                return $upload_path;
        }
```